# Error name not defined while trying to load Jupyter notebook from canopy version 2.1.3

Tags: package, jupyter-notebook, nameerror, canopy

I am running on Canopy version 2.1.3 and I keep getting a syntax error. I have tried using `ipython-notebook` as well as `jupyter-notebook` and both times I get back that ipython and jupyter are not defined. I've double checked and it looks like I have all the packages installed in order to use notebook and everything is up to date.

Comment: Please show the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your OS? Exactly what command are you entering, and from what kind of console? Please include an exact transcript (input and output) of your session. Also a link to the instructions that you are trying to follow.

For example, if you want to start a notebook from the command line, go to Canopy's tools menu, open a "Canopy Terminal / Command Prompt", and type `jupyter notebook`. Or, skip the command line and just use Canopy's File menu => New => Notebook.

Comment: Thank you! Using the File Menu worked! I'm used to using Anconda, not Canopy, so still trying to learn the ins and outs of it! This saved me a lot of hunting though.